# В ответе приходят крякозяюбры

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, rest, axios

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ответе от сервера мне приходят крякозябры, когда я сохраняю в excel через FileSaver то при открытии сам excel ругается на то что файл не валиден.
Может нужно другую кодировку в headers указать или проблема в самом ответе?

Comment: а на сайте какая кодировка?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin utf-8